# Using a single scanner input to assign two variables in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a method to search an arraylist for a student number (sNumber) that the user inputs, and then with that same input get the indexOf so it can pull data from other arraylists. The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to do this using a single input from the user. Right now for it to work they'd have to input the sNumber twice.

```
while (exit == 0){
            System.out.println("Please enter the sNumber of the student you wish to find");
            Boolean x = sNumber.contains(kb.nextInt());
            int y = sNumber.indexOf(kb.nextInt());

            if (x = true){
                String a = name.get(y);                        
                int c = sNumber.get(y);
                String d = major.get(y);
                Double e = gpa.get(y);

                System.out.println(a);                        
                System.out.println(c);
                System.out.println(d);
                System.out.println(e);
             }
            else if (x = false){
                System.out.println("This student does not exist");
```

Comment: `(x = true)` is assigning `true` to `x`, then taking the value of `x` for the `if`. Use `==` or just `x` for booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two `kb.nextInt()` are returning the same value why don't you just assign it to variable first then use it in the program later.

```
Boolean x = sNumber.contains(kb.nextInt());
int y = sNumber.indexOf(kb.nextInt());
```

would turn into

```
int tmp = kb.nextInt();
Boolean x = sNumber.contains(tmp);
int y = sNumber.indexOf(tmp);
```